# javascript, tree scrollIntoView won't scroll

Tags: javascript, html

I need to get all the links in a page, and i do get them, the problem is the href exist twice in the website, to not get the link twice i did a little trick with the variables :

```
getAlllinks: function()
{
    var links = content.document.getElementsByTagName("a");

    var entries = new Array;
    var liens = new Array;

    for(var i = 0; i<links.length; i++)
    {
        if(entries.indexOf(links[i].href) == -1)
        {
            entries.push(links[i].href);
            liens.push(links[i]);
        }
    }


    return links;
}
```

ok till now everything is fine, i put the links in a tree (Xul) and all, but my problem starts from here on, i use `scrollIntoView` to scroll to the link

```
var tree = document.getElementById("Tree_links");
var tbo = tree.boxObject;
var row = { }, col = { }, child = { };
tbo.getCellAt(event.clientX, event.clientY, row, col, child);
var cellText = tree.view.getCellText(row.value, col.value);

var links = new Array;
links = cleanLinks();

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) 
{
    if (links[i].href === cellText.toString()) 
    {
        links[i].scrollIntoView("true");
        if(links[i].style.backgroundColor == "rgb(255, 255, 0)")
        {
            links[i].style.backgroundColor='transparent';
        }
        else
        {
            links[i].style.backgroundColor='#ffff00';
        }
    }
}
```

it won't scroll for the links that are twice in the page, BUT if i put all the links (twice or single) in the tree it does scroll.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured it out,
the trick i was doing with the variables i did it when filling the tree